# JSON parsing on the shell

Tags: zsh, string, json

How can I parse JSON output on the shell?

For example, Amazon Web Services provides a CLI to retrieve the status of your instances:

```
$ aws ec2 describe-instances <my_instance_id>
```

But the command returns a JSON string. The output of that command looks like this:

```
$ aws ec2 describe-instances x12345
{
    "Reservations" :
     {  
            "OwnerId": "1345345"
            "Groups": [], 
            "SecurityGroups": [
               {
                  "Foo" : "yes"
                  "Bar" : "no
               }
             ]
     }
}
```

Are there an shells built-ins that could be used to parse JSON output?

For example, I would like to capture in a shell variable `FOO`, the following `output["Reservations"]["SecurityGroups"][0]{"Foo"}`.

In case it helps, I am specifically interested in solutions that could work from Zsh.

Comment: You would typically use a tool, like [jshon](http://kmkeen.com/jshon/).

Comment: Use `--output text` if you want to parse in the shell without using external tools like `jshon`.

Comment: @jasonwryan - Having only now heard of `jshon` for the first time, I followed your link. Having read that, I can only say that I left very pleased that I, by chance, heard of and installed `jq` first. I think you might like to hear of it too if you have not already - it doesn't bother with all of those command-line switches and can do its own regexes - it even allows you to declare functions and variables if you wish. See the answer here about it if you're interested.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As I understand it you're looking for the value of "Foo". This is *really* easy to do with the shell command-line tool `jq`. It is something like `sed` in that it implements its own kind of parser language. Given your example:

```
json='
{
    "Reservations" :
     {  
            "OwnerId" : "1345345",
            "Groups" :  [],
            "SecurityGroups" : [
               {
                  "Foo" : "yes",
                  "Bar" : "no"
               }
             ]
     }
}'
```

`jq` can get `yes` as simply as:

```
printf %s "$json" |
jq '.[].SecurityGroups[0].Foo?'
```

#### OUTPUT

```
"yes"
```

You can walk through an object hash or dictionary list using the `.dot` notation, and indexed arrays can be indexed more simply, with, as you have probably guessed, numeric, square-bracketed indices. In the command above I use the empty index form to indicate that I want all of that level's iterable items expanded. That may be easier to understand in this way:

```
printf %s "$json" | jq '.[][]'
```

... which breaks out all values for the second level items in the hash and gets me...

```
"1345345"
[]
[
  {
    "Foo": "yes",
    "Bar": "no"
  }
]
```

This barely scratches the surface with regards to `jq`'s capabilities. It is an immensely powerful tool for serializing data in the shell, it compiles to a single executable binary in the classic Unix-style, it is very likely available via package-manager for your distribution, and it is very well documented. Please visit its [`git`-page](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/) and see for yourself.

By the way, another way to tackle layered-data in `json` - at least to get an idea of what you're working with - might be to go the other way and use the `.dot` notation to break out *all* values at *all* levels like:

```
printf %s "$json" | jq '..'

{
  "Reservations": {
    "OwnerId": "1345345",
    "Groups": [],
    "SecurityGroups": [
      {
        "Foo": "yes",
        "Bar": "no"
      }
    ]
  }
}
{
  "OwnerId": "1345345",
  "Groups": [],
  "SecurityGroups": [
    {
      "Foo": "yes",
      "Bar": "no"
    }
  ]
}
"1345345"
[]
[
  {
    "Foo": "yes",
    "Bar": "no"
  }
]
{
  "Foo": "yes",
  "Bar": "no"
}
"yes"
"no"
```

But far better, probably, would be just to use one of the many discovery or search methods that `jq` offers for the various types of nodes.

Answer (score 13):

This is an answer to your objective, but not your question. Meaning you can accomplish your goal without using a JSON parser.

The AWS cli util has the ability to only output select fields using the `--query` argument. This is documented [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/controlling-output.html#controlling-output-filter).

For example:

```
$ aws ec2 describe-instances \
  --query 'Reservations[0].Instances[0].SecurityGroups[0].GroupName' \
  --instance-id i-6b272337 \
  --output text
mongodb
```

You can even select multiple fields if you'd like:

```
$ aws ec2 describe-instances \
  --query 'Reservations[0].Instances[0].SecurityGroups[0].[GroupName,GroupId]' \
  --instance-id i-6b272337 \
  --output text
mongodb sg-710ffa14
```

And you can show multiple matching structs as well:

```
$ aws ec2 describe-instances \
  --query 'Reservations[0].Instances[0].SecurityGroups[*].[GroupName,GroupId]' \
  --instance-id i-6b272337 \
  --output text
mongodb sg-710ffa14
default sg-a0243bcc
```

Comment: Thanks! That's very helpeful. I am accepting @mikeserv mostly to serve the community with the answer to the question, but your answer is the one I will be using

Comment: This is very helpful! Thank you very much!!