# How to make grep return value without comma

Tags: text-processing, grep

I want to extract a value from a json file so that I can process it and I try that using `grep '"USDEUR" currs.json' | cut -d ':' -f 2` but it returns `0.918695,` and the json file looks like this:

```
{
"success":true,
"terms":"https:\/\/currencylayer.com\/terms",
"privacy":"https:\/\/currencylayer.com\/privacy",
"timestamp":1449232988,
"source":"USD",
"quotes":{
  "USDEUR":0.918695,
  "USDGBP":0.660851,
  "USDPLN":3.95815
}
}
```

So I want to know how to disable the comma so that I can process the value of USDEUR

Comment: I have to point to http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159906/json-parsing-on-the-shell for examples of parsing json more reliably.

Answer (score 12):

Use a JSON parser to parse JSON, for example [`jq`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jq/info):

```
$ jq '.quotes.USDEUR' file.json 
0.918695
```

Comment: That's probably the sanest way of all; using the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 5):

There are a number of ways to do it.  You could pipe your results through any of the following

```
tr -d ','
cut -d',' -f1
sed -e 's/,//'
```

Answer (score 3):

With pure `grep` using perl compatible regular expressions (`-P` option):

```
grep -Po 'USDEUR":\K.*(?=,)' file
```

- `\K` will throw away everything till `:`
- `(?=,)` will throw away everything after `,` (including `,`)

Comment: One thing about this, if the USDEUR value is the _last_ in the list, it won't have a comma. Perhaps `'USDEUR":\K.*(?=,|$)'`

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule of thumb: if you pipe the output of a text tool (`grep` or `sed`) through `cut` you’re already doing something wrong. (Suggesting a second `cut` pipe is even more idiotic…)

```
sed -n '/"USDEUR"/s/^.*:\(.*\),$/\1/p'
```

This used [`sed`](https://www.mirbsd.org/man1/sed) in “don’t echo lines by default” mode (`-n`) with a [POSIX basic regular expression](https://www.mirbsd.org/man7/re_format) and a substitution, that basically says: on all lines matching “"USDEUR"”, replace the entire line by everything between the colon and a trailing comma, then output the line.

This won’t match if your line does *not* have a trailing comma. On the other hand, you seem to know your input is a numeric field, so just exclude commas:

```
sed -n '/"USDEUR"/s/^.*:\([^,]*\),*$/\1/p'
```

This replaces everything between a colon and the end of the line *that does not contain a colon*, and ignores any amount of trailing colons (zero or one, as your input is supposedly valid JSON).

Otherwise, [use a JSON parser](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/251201/43720) is the sensible thing to do. You could cobble together more regexes to also catch strings that may contain commas themselves, but… it isn’t worth it at some point, usually.

Answer (score 0):

Add another cut.

```
grep '"USDEUR" currs.json' | cut -d ':' -f 2 | cut -d',' -f 1
```